# Can see Ubuntu server on the network, but cannot connect

Tags: 14.04, networking

I can see my Ubuntu machine on the network, but I can't connect to it.

This is the second time this has happened in the last couple of days.  Last time, I rebooted the server and changed the network port and was able to connect again, but this time no.

I can see the server is on the network via my DD-WRT router:

[image]

Cannot connect to it using Putty:

[image]

Any ideas?  Is it a possible faulty network card?  It's a non-integrated card, and I've had many of these fail on me the past.  Wondering if it is starting to play up.
Could it be something else?

I also cannot ping the machine:

```
Pinging 192.168.1.17 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.2: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.2: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.2: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.2: Destination host unreachable.
```

Comment: Have you checked the firewall settings?

Comment: There's no firewall on the Ubuntu box.  It was connected last night (and for the last 2 years).  Woke up this morning and I can no longer connect.

Comment: The 'destination host unreachable' means that the device on 192.168.1.2 (your router? your laptop?) does not see 192.168.1.17 on the network. Are all cables connected properly? Are you sure you are on the same network  (maybe on another wifi network?).

Comment: The router is 192.168.1.1, PC is 192.168.1.2.  Please note that this has been connected for a long while and the configuration hasn't been changed at all. The only thing that is different is I have been doing a lot of SMB transfers to this box lately doing a full backup of my PC data (about 4.5TB). All hardwired, no Wifi involved.

Comment: Just noticed there was traffic going out of the box at a high rate, so I turned off port forwarding to that machine and the traffic disappeared.  However I still cannot get into it.  Starting to think it may have been hacked into from the interwebs.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out it had nothing to do with the Ubuntu machine in the end. Nor was it someone hacking the machine from the net, but instead a faulty switch box, which wasn't correctly routing traffic.